# Lowercase "u" not typing anywhere in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, input

This problem happened with me twice on two different Ubuntu environments.

Everything seems to be working fine, until suddenly I cannot type the lowercase letter "u" anymore.

I can type uppercase "U" using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, and I can run any commands that includes the letter, but I can't type "u" anywhere.

It seems that the keyboard has no problem and the issue is coming from the OS itself.

Comment: Read `man dumpkeys` (`dumpkeys` is part of the `kbd` package), and look at the results of `sudo dumpkeys -i;sudo dumpkeys -l`.

Comment: I looked at it, and the letter "u" was there lower and upper cases.